# How to Use Angular Routing from Child Component Using Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-routing

I am trying to set up routing on a toolbar component that I created. The toolbar component is called in my app.component and that's how it is added to the DOM. I have a menu with 3 buttons on that toolbar and I would like to make them route to different links.

I tried importing AngularRouting into my child component (toolbar) but I am not sure what I'm doing anymore lol.

./toolbar/toolbar.ts:

```
     <button mat-menu-item>
       <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
       <span>Home</span>
     </button>
     <button mat-menu-item>
       <mat-icon>assignment</mat-icon>
       <span>About</span>
     </button>
     <button mat-menu-item>
       <mat-icon>help</mat-icon>
       <span>Help</span>
     </button>
   </mat-menu>
```

How do I setup routing on the child component that uses angular material?

Comment: Setting up routing may be not that simple. did you have a look to Angular tutorial (ToH) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved in several ways.

1. using routerLink

   ```
   <button routerLink='/home' mat-menu-item>
      <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
      <span>Home</span>
    </button>
   ```

2 using .ts file
HTML

```
     <button (click)="navigateToHome()" mat-menu-item>
       <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
       <span>Home</span>
     </button>
```

TS

```
constructor(private router:Router){}

navigateToHome(){
this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
}
```

using Angular material doesn't change the way you navigate.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This worked for me! I ended up adding routerlinks! Thanks for the help!!